# How do I run all Ansible plays at first host (all of them), then at second host (all of them) and so on - hosts one by one?

Tags: ansible

This is for a set of hosts, where no more than one host with a service may be down at time and host's set up may be a complex routine. I already tried `serial: 1` (it's Rolling Update in Ansible terms), `--limit $host`, `--fork 1`. All of them works in undesirable way: it still running play by play instead of host by host.

Here are current properties and desired ones for a solution (it's a matter of subject and it's possible to rewrite solution from scratch too):

- I have set of playbooks - ready for use solution.
- I want to run this solution against each host one by one.
- Inventory is created with Python logic before a launch of a play (it's done).
- Hosts already are spread across arbitrary set of groups. Certain hosts are only members of one group, certain host are members of another group only. I have *dynamic* inventory (Ansible Dynamic inventory feature) and in inventory always have auto-generated group with plain list of *all* hosts involved.

Looking for how to:

- All plays should be ran at a first host and finish.
- All plays should be ran at a second host and finish.
- And so on at arbitrary quantity of hosts.
- If a host is not from a group for a playbook, play should not be applied at this host.

Advise me please: How may I achieve it?

Below are simplified parts of the plays set. It have been created and generally it works.

My top level playbook `site.yaml`

```
---
-   name: Site set up
    hosts:
        - masters
        - replicas
    serial: 1
    roles:
        - role: do-01
        - role: do-02

-   import_playbook: play-do-11.yaml
-   import_playbook: play-do-12.yaml
```

I have play books: `play-do-11.yaml`, `play-do-12.yaml` like this:

```
---
-   name: play-do-11
    hosts: satellites
    serial: 1
    roles:
        -   role: actor
```

I'm starting Ansible playbook in this way:

```
for single_host in  host-a  host-b  host-c ; do
    ansible-playbook \
        --forks 1 \
        --limit "$single_host" \
        --inventory inventory.json \
        "site.yaml"
done
```

P.S. It's out of scope, but it adds flexibility to a solution I'm looking for. In fact I have dynamic inventory. It can be launched before any other items launch. There is auto-added group with plain list of all hosts in the inventory. Thus, I can create pre-generated Json and before a launch I have all host name's as plain strings. It is used in Shell launcher like this:

```
for host in $( cat inventory.json | jq -r ".\"group-with-all\".hosts | keys[]" ) ; do
    ansible-playbook --limit "${host}" ...
done
```

It's well enough for automation: hosts grouping and properties still are managed in one place.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain what does "a host match a group for this role" mean?  Or, in other words, what does "a group for a role" mean? Shouldn't this be rather "a group for this play"?

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it, may be no need to mention this condition.

Yes, in other words:

If a host is not from a group for a playbook, play should not be applied at this host.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"All plays should be run at a first host and finish. All plays should be run at a second host and finish. And so on at arbitrary quantity of hosts."***

A: It's not possible. The scope of [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) and [strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#selecting-a-strategy) is a play. All hosts shall complete a play before the next one can be started. An import of a playbook is equivalent to starting a new play.

Q: ***"If a host is not from a group for a playbook, play should not be applied to this host."***

A: It's possible to create a new group in the first play and use it in the imported playbooks. For example, the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[satellites]
test_03
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat play-do-11.yml
- hosts: my_dynamic_group

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

imported from the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat site.yml
- hosts: test

  tasks:

    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_dynamic_group
      loop: "{{ groups.test }}"
      when: item in groups.satellites
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname

- import_playbook: play-do-11.yml
```

---

Note: Optionally, [intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) the groups and omit the condition:

```yaml
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_dynamic_group
      loop: "{{ groups.test|intersect(groups.satellites) }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook site.yml

PLAY [test] ***

TASK [add_host] ***
skipping: [test_01] => (item=test_01) 
skipping: [test_01] => (item=test_02) 
changed: [test_01] => (item=test_03)

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [test_01] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_01"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_03"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_02"
}

PLAY [my_dynamic_group] ***

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [test_03] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "test_03"
}

PLAY RECAP ***
```

Comment: Awesome, thats what i needed(the idea that that new host group is available to run in a new play).  So in the first play i add hosts to a new group when they are skipped for reasons, then i duplicate that play to run again using the new host group, ensures that the new group of hosts that were skipped is then ran after the other hosts that weren't skipped, in the 2nd (duplicate) play, using the new hostgroup.  Thanks!!